# Memmove и realloc

Tags: c

Скажите, что здесь может быть не так? Удаление из массива pnt* point размера Pointscount элементов элемента с индексом index и изменение размеров этого массива. Гарантируется, что память под массив будет выделена.

Тип pnt - структура, включающая в себя int x и int y.

```
void RemovePoint(int index)
    {
        if(index<pointscount)
        {

            memmove(points + index*(sizeof(pnt)),points + (index+1)*(sizeof(pnt)),sizeof(pnt)*(pointscount - index - 1));
            points = (pnt*)realloc(points,sizeof(pnt)*(--pointscount));
        }
    }
```

Работает некорректно, не вызывает ошибок, но содержимое массива не соответствует ожидаемому.Пример:

Входные данные: {{100,100},{150,100},{200,200}}.(Точки с координатами)

Результат(index = 0):

[0]:1281315407 1279612475 ; Должно быть: 150 100

[1]:1342191165 1162039122 ; Должно быть: 200 200

Что может быть не так??

Answer (score 4):

Судя по всему, вы ошиблись в адресной арифметике.

Если я правильно догадался, тип `point` — `struct pnt *`. Поэтому при прибавлении к нему числа, сдвиг считается не в байтах, а в записях.

То есть вам нужно вместо `points + index*(sizeof(pnt))` просто `points + index` (или `&points[index]`).

Comment: Огромное спасибо, все заработало!

Comment: @Alexander: пожалуйста!